# WPF OpacityMask weird behavior

Tags: wpf, xaml, opacitymask

I think I might have found a bug in WPF, or maybe I just don't fully understand how OpacityMasks work. As you can see on the first image, I have a diamond shaped path and a red circle. My goal is to make everything outside the diamond invisible. It works when the circle is inside the diamond shape, but whenever I move it to one of the corners, or outside the path, the OpacityMask seems to get stretched or distorted as you can see on the second image. My question is how can I make the OpacityMask work regardless of where the circle (or any other child element) is.

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hawYQ.png)

[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyqLF.png)

And this is my XAML code

```
<Grid Name="rootGrid">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=path}"/>
        </Grid.OpacityMask>
        <Path Name="path" 
              Stretch="Fill" 
              Fill="Cyan" 
              StrokeThickness="1" 
              Stroke="GreenYellow" 
              Data="M 0,-1 1,0 0,1 -1,0 0,-1"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="Red" 
                 Margin="20,-17,22,61"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Sorry for posting the images with links, but I don't have enough reputation to directly embed images.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is not a bug. The VisualBrush is stretched to the whole visible Grid area, which ranges vertically from -17 to the Grid's ActualHeight. Set `ViewportUnits="Absolute"` on the VisualBrush, and then set its Viewport property to an appropriate rectangle, e.g. `Viewport="0,0,100,100"`

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clemens solved my issue

> Set ViewportUnits="Absolute" on the VisualBrush, and then set its Viewport property to an appropriate rectangle, e.g. Viewport="0,0,100,100"